# Does ducting help to stabilise heavy lift drones?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, stability

I'm looking to build a UAV that is extremely stable. It doesn't have to be fast, it doesn't have to be agile, but it will have to carry up to 50lbs (agriculture focused UAV that has to operate for at least 8 hours at a time) over private land (where the drone is authorized to be, and with FAA registration) at an altitude of about 15 feet.

Is ducting the way to go here?

I'm looking to do a quadcopter with a very very low center of gravity right now because of it's inherent stability. Is ducting or more rotors the way to go here? And I have very few specifics because I'm still working on the basics of the platform. It will have to carry a lot of weight and potentially deal with being thrown off balance by a rover getting caught on plants.

Comment: very low center of gravity does not necessarily means it will be more stable. It will dampen pitch and roll by acting like a pendulum. Instead having the cog closer to propellers' plane will allow quicker attitude corrections on both of these axis.

Comment: Just wondering, have you done any calculations to figure out how many watts you will need to keep the vehicle airborne?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm guessing batteries are actually going to be most of the weight of it. I'm fairly new to this, perhaps unsurpisingly, so I may find that as I progress on this changes will have to be made because i'll find that my original goals are unrealistic.

Comment: As @qqjkztd said, that doesn't necessarily help stability. See [the Pendulum Rocket Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_rocket_fallacy). Note that the idea applies to more than just rockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is too little information given to make a definite answer here, but things you should take into consideration are:

- depending on the construction the bigger crosssection if keeping a similar rotorsize which will likely increase drag at higher windspeeds while on the other hand leading the airflow so with the right construction it might behave better then without ducting.
- using at least 6 or better 8 rotors should enable you to increase lifting power and stability
- putting the rotors in an angled position should increase stability while it might slightly reduce lifting power

additionally

- the ducting will offer protection for the rotors/fans and people/things getting hit by the drone in case of a crash
- as you want too operate it for such a long time the increase in weight which might increase the number of refuels/battery changes needed

Also we were talking about drones that produce the whole lift by rotors pushing air downwards. What about using a ballon or some kind of plane? This will make it more sensitive towards wind and sacrifice maneuverability but will allow extended flight time and potentially higher efficiency.

Comment: Thank you for the information, sensitivity to wind will be a major issue. The purpose is for mapping moisture, ph, spotting disease and animal damage automatically and a few other things as well. It's going to have to hover in places while it drops a "rover" from it to take soil readings then retract it back up.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty advanced project to me as dropping and lifting a rover will cause forces that most drones are not programmed for. I guess the rover is done already? Also most drones have flight times under 30 minutes, landing or hovering only a few centimetres over the ground might be necessary if the rover takes a while to collect samples as otherwise you would have to carry insanely large batterypacks or use fuel.

Comment: The rover isn't done yet, I have some of the sensors and some of the software done. I can't think of another way to allow both normal farm equipment to operate, and to get the necessary readings than using. An aerial vehicle to navigate the fields themselves. I chose 50lbs as a somewhat arbitrary worst case scenario. I'll obviously do everything I can to keep it light. The UAV will stop drop the rover. And hover at around 15 feet. The rover needs to be able to drop to the soil extend it's sensors move off a lump of dirt that's in the way and go back up.

Comment: I've thought about using fuel but that seems like another layer of complication. I also thought about using mini jet engines for their thrust and control, but there's too much risk of fire in a dry field. So I think insane amounts of battery packs it might be. This would have to cover hundreds of acres at a time. I might be able to make it modular. But ease of use is key here. This is why I'm here though, I have plenty of experience in electronics, coding, and data modeling. Aviation not so much :-)

Comment: Does it have to be a rover or could it also just be a plate with like nails to provide grip and a drill? Either dropped with a wind by the drone or fixed to the drone which then lands on it. What kind of land are you measuring? Is it just gras or big stuff like corn?

Comment: Big stuff like corn is one of the major places to use this. And as of 2014 the average size of a farm in Kansas was 747 acres. Eventually it would be linked with a database and could recommend different varieties of corn or even new crops based on the soil conditions. And it doesn't need a drill. It needs to be able to move off of lumps of dirt though so it doesn't get stuck.

Comment: Also this sound like a rather expensive drone, you might want to ask an engineer to run a simulation, after a physicist checked your number are right 

Comment: Might need to. So far I'm only in this project about 100USD. Goal is to keep it under about 3k total.

Answer (score 0):

Ducted fans, as far as I know, don't increase the stability of a drone. They do have a positive effect on the efficiency of the propellors, if and only if, the airflow is more or less without any incidence (where the "more or less" is heavily effected by the shape of the ducts). So for outside use, as well as racing etc. ducts are not the way to go from a efficiency and/or stability perspective. Safety considerations are still a valid reason to choose for them.

Regarding the low center of gravity, make sure you don't overdo it. While it does increase the stability, it also makes the system slower to compensate, which will be felt in gusty conditions. It will be worse at keeping position.