# Is it practical to use wires to stiffen rotor arms?

Tags: aircraft-design, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

(Related to [my last question on ducting](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/49117/62).)

Wires have been used in the past to stabilize wings with a very low weight cost. Could something similar be use to stabilize the arms for a UAV's rotors?

Assuming I don't have enough money to build a custom 8 arm (based on previous advice) carbon fiber frame, could the wiring approach be applied to UAVs? I ask because for a V1 prototype PVC is cheap and relatively strong, but I could enhance it with a bit of aluminum plate in the center and small aircraft cable in tension.

Comment: What kind of wire are you thinking of using?

Comment: I was thinking 1/16 aircraft cable top and bottom to put the arm in tension. Could also go with nylon to save weight but I would be concerned about it stretching and ultimately failing.

Comment: I mean, I see little reason why not. The only issue I could see appearing is that the wire on top might intersect the prop circle.

Comment: I thought of that too. Obviously I'll have to keep that from happening. It'll probably only go about halfway out the arm, but it will still reduce the flex of the arm significantly. Thanks.

Comment: And ifconfig if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it. Like the name btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see little reason why small gauge wire couldn't be used to strengthen rotor arms on a multirotor. The only major issue I could see developing is that the wire on the top side of the arm might accidentally intersect the prop circle.

**MS Paint sketch of a possible design idea:**

[image: pardon my extremely excellent MS Paint skills]